# Как вывести максимально приблеженное число

Tags: php

Нужно найти максимально приближенное число с верху к введенному из массива.

```
$number = 16;
$mass = array(41,17.48,12,9,15.32);
```

Должно вывести 17.48, если число например 18 программа должна вывести 32.

Comment: и ваши наработки где?

Comment: При 18 ближайшее большее это 41, если только вы не перепутали точку с запятой у `15.32`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mass = array(41,17.48,12,9,15.32);
$number = 16;
$current = PHP_INT_MAX; // максимально большое целое
foreach ($mass as $value) {
    // Если значение из массива больше заданного и меньше текущего
    // то меняем ближайшее текущее
    if( ($number < $value) && ($value < $current)) {
        $current = $value;
    }
}
echo $current;
```